# Xamarin.Android erro "PresentationFramework"

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Eu estou com esse erro no meu projeto Xamarin.android

- Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
  Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
  Could not load assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't
  exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
  'PresentationFramework.dll' at
  Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
  reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at
  Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
  reference) at
  Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
  resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
  Boolean topLevel) at
  Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
  resolver) Project.Novo

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Guii, fica difícil obter uma resposta se você não indicar quando foi que esse erro começou a acontecer ou disponibilizar parte do código que você acha que pode estar gerando esse erro.

Comment: ocorreu depois q eu peguei o projeto de outra pasta tipo eu copiei ele para outro local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui corrigir adicionando a referencia da pasta "Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\'VERSION\'Nome da DLL'".